# How is hardware (/dev nodes) accessed from with a snap?

Tags: snap

How would one configure a snap package to include access to an arbitrary /dev?

For example, say a kernel driver provides access to some really neato hardware via /dev/foo and a user-space snap contains a daemon which wants to read and write to /dev/foo.  Is it possible to provide the snapped service with that access?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extend the sandbox for a snap using 'interfaces'. A particular interface describes a special relationship between two snaps. For example, 'mysql' might describe the fact that a database and an app want to talk over a shared socket. Normally, they would be sandboxed and unable to see the same file, but if one provides the interface (a "slot") and one consumes the interface (a "plug") then their sandboxes are both extended appropriately.

In your case, you need to design the appropriate interface and contribute a patch to snapd that allows snaps to describe themselves with that plug or slot.

In the case of devices, we conceptualise that as the snap "plugging into the system", so the slot is notionally on the "kernel snap". Essentially snapd is the place to focus. Read some about plugs, slots and interfaces and take a loot at the snapd code.